# Allow ordering "deleted comments by" page by deletion date

Tags: feature-request, comments, moderator-tools

When reviewing automatic "possible vandalism: comment deletions" flags, I usually go to mod > info > comments > deleted to review what's been going on.

Currently, the list is ordered only by comment creation date, and can't be ordered by deletion date. Folks are often purging old comments (like 'possible duplicate of' and other such obsolete comments), but there isn't a single place to review these.

It'd be advantageous to order that list by comment deletion date when reviewing these flags. Can we get a tab for that?